# filter and map results into a new array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of products that are filtered and then mapped, this works correctly but I would like to push the results into a new array
so I can then sort the results or check if there are no results returned

I have tried to `concat` the results of map into a new array but I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined`

```
class ProductsList extends React.Component {
  state ={
    filteredProducts: []
  }
  render() {
    const { e, p, filteredColors, filteredSizes, filteredProducts,  match, products } = this.props
    return(
      <Section>
        <Container>
          <Grid>

            {products && products.filter(products =>
            (
              (filteredColors.length >= 1 && filteredSizes.length < 1 && products.cat === match.params.subCatId) && filteredColors.includes(products.color) ||
              (filteredSizes.length >= 1 && filteredColors.length < 1 && products.cat === match.params.subCatId) && filteredSizes.includes(products.size) ||

              (filteredSizes.length >= 1 && filteredColors.length >= 1 && products.cat === match.params.subCatId) && filteredColors.includes(products.color) && filteredSizes.includes(products.size)) ||
              (filteredSizes.length < 1 && filteredColors.length < 1 && products.cat === match.params.subCatId)
            )
            .map(product =>
              <div>
              {filteredProducts.concat(product.id)}
              {console.log(filteredProducts)}
              </div>
              // <Cell key={product.id}>
              //     <ProductListCard e={e} p={p} match={match}{...product} />
              // </Cell>
            )}
          </Grid>
        </Container>
        <Filters>
          <Filter />
        </Filters>
      </Section>
    )
  }
}

export default ProductsList
```

Comment: Sounds like your prop `filteredProducts` is actually `undefined`? Did you mean to define a `defaultProps` rather than create a state key?

Comment: ah I see where im going wrong, Im trying to access filteredProducts as an object instead of from state

Answer (score 0):

I have defined my filters to  `const filteredProducts`  so the results are now accesible via this variable

```
class ProductsList extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { e, p, filteredColors, filteredSizes,  match, products } = this.props
    const filteredProducts = products && products.filter(products =>
      (
        (filteredColors.length >= 1 && filteredSizes.length < 1 && products.cat === match.params.subCatId) && filteredColors.includes(products.color) ||
        (filteredSizes.length >= 1 && filteredColors.length < 1 && products.cat === match.params.subCatId) && filteredSizes.includes(products.size) ||

        (filteredSizes.length >= 1 && filteredColors.length >= 1 && products.cat === match.params.subCatId) && filteredColors.includes(products.color) && filteredSizes.includes(products.size)) ||
        (filteredSizes.length < 1 && filteredColors.length < 1 && products.cat === match.params.subCatId)
      )
      console.log(filteredProducts)
    return(
      <Section>
        <Container>
          <Grid>
            {filteredProducts && filteredProducts.map(filteredProduct =>
              <Cell key={filteredProduct.id}>
                <ProductListCard e={e} p={p} match={match}{...filteredProduct} />
              </Cell>
            )}
          </Grid>
        </Container>
        <Filters>
          <Filter />
        </Filters>
      </Section>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter and map into a new array you can use reduce

```
const filterMap = (array, condition, transform) =>
  array ?
        array.reduce((results, item) => (condition(item) ? [...results, transform(item)] : results), [])
        : array;
```

Now you have a filterMap function that will return a new array in a single iteration instead of two.